# When to store just the ID in a class vs storing a fully-populated object?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have two tables as below:

```
FoodType:

ID | Name       |  ... additional fields ...
---------------------------------------------
1  | Fruit      | ...
2  | Vegetable  | ...
```

```
Food:

ID | FoodTypeId | Name
----------------------
1  | 1          | Apple
2  | 1          | Orange
3  | 2          | Carrot
4  | 2          | Spinach
5  | 1          | Pear
```

When I'm structuring a class for `Food`, in what cases would it be better to define just `FoodTypeId` instead of a whole `FoodType` object?

i.e.

```
public class Food
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int FoodTypeId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

vs

```
public class Food
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public FoodType FoodType {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class FoodType
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: "Better" how? It's difficult to say stuff like this without knowing how you intend to use things.  Is this in a webpage?  A database?  A windows service?

Comment: It really depends on the DAL/ORM used, no? A manual/simple DAL/ORM would mandate this decision here - e.g. there is no mechanism to build out so it's a one-shot load/store (which isn't necessarily bad). Something more sophisticated like LINQ2SQL, EF, nHibernate, etc, would "transparently" connect the object graph. (Of course there are many more details: caching, lazy/immediate loading, etc.)

Comment: @pst Some of those more sophisticated options give you the choice of which you want; I assume the OP is asking why anyone would want to use one over the other.

Comment: @Servy From a programming perspective (with no consideration to any other system operation/interaction) there is only one choice - a way to access the graph in a nicely connected manner, no? Otherwise each access through a relation requires an inversion to fetch-by-ID (or whatever it is) and maintaining state, which is "cumbersome".

Comment: @pst I'm just saying that I've worked with query providers that give you the option of disabling these complex referential fields, and I've had situations where I've found it to be worth doing.  I can see why someone new to the topic might ask why you would ever intentionally choose the less robust option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to just store the ID if you infrequently need to use the other information about the FoodType object, and fetching and populating that information takes a noticeable amount of effort.

You would want to store an actual food type object if you frequently use the additional information or the effort to populate it is sufficiently small.

There are of course other hybrid situations, such as the object having both an ID and an actual object, but having the actual object be 'null' instead of populated in certain situations, or to have an actual object that only populates certain fields in the referenced object.  Even more sophisticated options will have the actual object, rather than an id, but populate it lazily or eagerly based on its usage.

Comment: I can't argue with this answer, but my two cents: I've built my own ID-connected "O-M" before. It was small. It was cute. It support the repository pattern. It was a mistake. (Not a terrible mistake, as the project and connected dependencies were limited, but it was a mistake none-the-less. The issue was lack of expandability compared to "real" ORMs; be it model-compilers or on-the-fly.)

Comment: @pst It really depends on context.  For example, when working with the SharePoint ORM I've found it extremely advantageous to have a field that is just the foreign key, rather than a complex object, either in addition to or instead of the complex type, simply because of the way SharePoint, and my applications, work.  Is it a bit unusual, sure, is it something you shouldn't ever do, as a blanket rule, no.

Comment: @pst That depends on the application.  You can certainly treat it as one, and I have.  Also keep in mind that lookup fields are, underneath, just relational models that the sharepoint tier abstracts away from you.

Comment: I'm not ruling out "letting the model decide". I'm warning against "creating a system like this" (read: manually). If I *were* to do it manually again, it would only be with support of templates (Codesmith or even TT4, eg).

Comment: @pst I'd warn against creating a model like this manually vs using an ORM in general; regardless of what decisions you make in your model.  It's a lot of work that you need to put in, so it needs to be significantly superior to an ORM for that work to pay off.